Spaces being incorrectly removed from text strings when importing data into Sheets
I have spreadsheet data that I want to import to Google Sheets.  The source spreadsheet is a proprietary format; neither Google Sheets nor MS Excel.
The issue I'm running into is that I have columns that include text strings as well as spaces, for example, in "1) " , ": " , and " - ", there are spaces in each string.
When I paste the data into a sheet, the trailing spaces are being automatically removed and, in the case of the dash  " - ", the leading space is removed as well. Changing the paste option, such as using 'paste values', doesn't solve my problem.
I have tried first exporting the source data to a CSV file, and then importing that CSV into the sheet, but the results were mixed. For example, the spaces around the dash  " - " were not removed, however, the trailing spaces after the parenthesis "1) "  and the colon ": " were still being removed.
When I open the same CSV file in Excel, it doesn't remove the spaces from the strings.
Does anybody know a way to fix this issue in Sheets?
Thanks

If you can add  a single quote at the beginning of the text string prior to importing that might address it.  "' - "
